# Adding data to a database using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm currently trying to use C# to add data into an access database (saved as mdb) here is my current code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private OleDbConnection bookConn;
        private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        private String connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Project\example.mdb;Persist Security Info=False";


        public Form1()
        {
            bookConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void add()
        {
            try
            {
                bookConn.Open();
                oleDbCmd.Connection = bookConn;
                oleDbCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Module) VALUES ('"+ this.textBox1.Text +"','"+ this.textBox2.Text +"');";
                oleDbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int temp = oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (temp > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Added");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                }
                bookConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add();
        }


    }
}
```

When i run this code i get the error message : *Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.*

I can't work out what i'm doing wrong when i compare to other examples it seems to be set up right.

Any help to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add those values as sqlParameters to prevent SQL injection, please.

Comment: Is StudentID supposed to be a `string` or an `int`?

Comment: what data types are student ID and Module?

Comment: And the first comment may be solving your problem too, maybe it's cause by a non-escaped quote character in your textbox ?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel it's going to be a string

Comment: are only these 2 fields supposed to be not null on Student table?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly stating the database name or `dbo` in front of the table name? (e.g. `dbo.Student`, etc.)

Comment: @BradM i'll add those values by sqlParameters and come back

Comment: @apomene - that won't matter - he is filling them both with strings, and he put the quotes directly in the query - at the very least, it will insert an empty string

Comment: The `sqlParameters` that @BradM mentioned won't solve the problem unless the issue is with un-escaped quotes. You never answered @Bartdude - do you have un-escaped quotes in the value from your textbox?

Comment: Hey guys, HansUp answer was correct, Module was a reserved word, and that was what was causing the problem, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#M).  Rename the field if possible/practical.  If you must keep that as the field name, enclose it in square brackets in your `INSERT` statement.

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, [Module]) VALUES ('"+ this.textBox1.Text +"','"+ this.textBox2.Text +"');";
```

Comment: If you follow the advice to switch to a parameter query, you should still bracket that field name.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked like a charm, and i am swapping to parameters now. Will accept the answer when the time is up.